# edit code in javascript file with python code

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to autocreate repititive code for an app using python backend. I wish to add a few lines of javascript code to a js file with python script. Can someone please guide me?

My code is shown below:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/static/partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('/hello', {
            templateUrl: '/static/partials/hello.html',
            controller: 'HelloController'
        })
    }
]);
```

I want  to add another url '/index' dynamically from backend which is in python.

So after adding code , it should look as follows:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/static/partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('/hello', {
            templateUrl: '/static/partials/hello.html',
            controller: 'HelloController'
        })
        .when('/index', {
            templateUrl: '/static/partials/index.html',
            controller: 'IndexController'
        })
    }
]);
```

Comment: Are you looking to print text to a file in python?  Check the [documentation for input and output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: I am trying to edit code in a javascript file (.js extension) with python script.

Comment: Is this a wrong way to dynamically add code. The question got a downvote..just trying to clarify?

Comment: Good that you add code to give an example, that usually prevents downvotes :) but anyway, I could answer your question, but won't it be much better to do it within Javascript? That's what functions are for...

Comment: Yeah, I can do with javascript too. Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
f = open("<<path of your js file>>.js", 'b')
f.write("console.log('it works');")
f.close()
```

The 'b' is the mode in which the open function operates

mode are 'r' for reading, 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and 'a' for appending

Please refer to python documentation below.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: a .js file is basically a text file, why open it as binary? also, if you open it like that, you can't even write to it, just read. why not use `with`? you're explaining `b` mode but don't say anything about using it with the other modes. This is a bad answer

Comment: @OferSadan you should append 'b' to the mode value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability. (Appending 'b' is useful even on systems that don’t treat binary and text files differently,

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @savinaynarendra Instead of doing this in python, can you have a http call to the python backend which returns the required route details, then you can add the details manually using route provider

`var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("./fetchIndex")
.then(function(response) {
        $scope.route = response.data;
   routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: '/' + $scope.route});
    });
});`
this is how I did for my angular-python flask web app, however I use UI router for routing,also, routeprovider is avaiable globally

Comment: Use this fucntion to insert any number of lines, provided you know the line number to insert on:
`def insert_code(filepath, text_to_insert, line_needed):
    temp=""
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i == line_needed:
                temp = temp + text_to_insert + "\n"
            else:
                temp = temp + line
        f.close()
    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
        f.write(temp)
        f.close()`
Use the in string operator for finding a particular text in string.
`if "particular string" in i:`